# create adobe air native extension in java

Tags: java, air, air-native-extension

I have to create a Native Extension to access network files on air. I have a desktop application on air. Searched the web to create an air extension by using java. There are lots of documents but both of  them for Android or iOS. So they are so complicated for a newbie.
 Do you know any document or link explains simply how to create air extension on java for Windows ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is the information from Adobe web site but never forget that java API only works for Android ARM platform, I mean doesn't work for Air Apps and iOS

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSff7e9115a8550eef-4b2a6195132502c4d38-8000.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the two following links for a step-by-step process on how to create .ane files.
http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=148
http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=149

By downloading the videos and also .ane file that are given, you actually get what structure you have to follow. Then create a bat file save it in .ane code folder

---

The command then is:
*"path of adt bat file located in airsdk"* -package  -target ane *"ane file name"*
 *"location of extension xml*" -swc  "location of .swc file"  -platform Android-ARM -C ./build/ane/Android-ARM/ .

For example:

"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722\AIRSDK\bin\adt.bat" -package -target ane upload.ane ./build/ane/extension.xml -swc ./build/ane/*.swc -platform Android-ARM -C ./build/ane/Android-ARM/ .